# Given a Group, $G =A_5$.Then choose correct statement

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given  $G =A_5$.Then

choose  correct statement

$a)$$ G$ one  sylow  $3$  subgroup

$b)$ $G$ has four sylow  $3 $ subgroup

$c)$ $G$  has ten sylow  $3$  subgroup

My attempt :  In my View  I thinks None of the  option  will  correct ,

but My friends  said in my hostel  when i was taking lunch , that  option $c)$  will correct.

my logics  is that   option a)  will not  correct  because  G is  simple

option $b)$  will not correct  because number of  element of order  $3$  in $S_4$  is not equal to  number of element of oder $3$ in $A_5$

similarly same logic  in option $c)$  that is number of  element of order  $3$  in $S_{10}$  is not equal to  number of element of order $3$ in $A_5$

so, None  of the option will correct..

Is  its True ?

Any hints/solution will be apprecaited

thanks u

Comment: I don't know what $S_4$ and $S_{10}$ have to do with anything.

Comment: @Slade   $ 1+ 3k |60$   i put $k=0,1,3$

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: ...@Slade  see  $1 + 3.1  = 4$  is  that $n_3 =  4$, so i take $S_4$ similarly   $1+3.3= 10,$ so i take $S_{10}$

Comment: I see, you're constructing a map $A_5 \to S_{10}$.  But this map isn't an isomorphism, so the fact that $S_{10}$ has more elements of order $3$ than $A_5$ does is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand your explanation about number of elements in $S_4$ and $S_{10}$. Anyway, using Sylow theorems we can see that one of the three options must be correct. Option $a$ is not correct because $G$ is simple, you got it right. Option $b$ is not correct because of the following: suppose $G$ has four $3$-Sylow subgroups. We can define an action of $G$ on $Syl_3(G)$ by $g.P=gPg^{-1}$. I'll leave it to you to check that it is indeed an action. Now, an action gives a homomorphism $\varphi:G\to S_{Syl_3(G)}$ by $\varphi(g)(P)=g.P=gPg^{-1}$. The group $G$ is simple and hence the homomorphism must be either trivial or one to one. It is not trivial because Sylow subgroups are conjugate to each other. And it is obviously not one to one because there can't be a function from a set with $60$ elements to a set with $4!=24$ elements which is one to one. A contradiction.

Comment: @Marks  from ur last sentence  even 10 !  will also  get  contradiction  ..can  u elaborate that

Comment: Why will you get a contradiction? $10!$ is a number which is much bigger than $60$. There is no reason why there can't be an injective function from a set of $60$ elements to a set of $10!$ elements. In my answer I simply used the fact that $60>4!$.

Comment: okss ,thanks u @Marks  i got  its

Answer (score 2):

$|G| = 60 = 2^2\cdot 3\cdot5$, so each Sylow 3-subgroup has order $3$.

Check that every set ${a,b,c}$ of three elements from $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ uniquely determines a subgroup of order 3, namely $\{(), (abc), (acb)\}$.  Check that every order 3 subgroup of $A_5$ is of this form.

Then the number of Sylow 3-subgroups is just ${5 \choose 3} = 10$.

Comment: ..@Slade  is their any formula to find the  number  of  sylow  p-subgroup ??

Comment: @jasmine For symmetric groups in general?  No, this is a difficult research problem.

Comment: okss @Slade....